# Mapping custom array in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array like this:

```
let strNames = ["banana", "apple", "mango"]
```

I am looking for a result like this:

```
var abc = [Fruit(id: 0, name: "banana"), Fruit(id: 1, name: "apple"), Fruit(id: 2, name: "mango")]
```

In classic way I can do so far. Can anybody please help me mapping in Swift way?

```
var abc: [Fruit] = []
for i in 0..<strNames.count {
   abc.append(Fruit(id: i, name: strNames[i]))
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012205/map-or-reduce-with-index-in-swift/28012291) answer your question?

Comment: Please include `Fruit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializers can be used as functions using this syntax.

```swift
["banana", "apple", "mango"].enumerated().map(Fruit.init)
```

It appears that your `Fruit` type matches up with [EnumeratedSequence.Element](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/enumeratedsequence/iterator/element) exactly.

```swift
struct Fruit {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
}
```

If it didn't, you'd just need to create your own closure.

```swift
["banana", "apple", "mango"].enumerated().map {
  Fruit(id: $0.offset, name: $0.element)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Sweeper for your suggestions. Actually this is what I am looking for...

```
let abc: [Fruit] = strNames.enumerated().map { Fruit(id: $0, name: $1) }
```